# How does Block-diagonal Schur factorization in Matlab works?

Tags: matlab

Can anyone explain how does the `bdschur` command of Matlab works? And how should the `CONDMAX` and `BLKS` be specified? It would be better if there is an associated example.

Source: https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bdschur.html